# React Native "No bundle URL present" only on ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I am getting this red screen with this well-known error :

"No bundle URL present. Make sure you're running..."

[image]

The problem is : I only get this red screen **while using my own iPhone**, building the code on Xcode.

**The app works well when using an emulator.**

I tested the majority of the fixes when people faced this issue (with the emulator) and it didn't fix my problem.

Also, I have been checking if the server was accessible, it seems to be ok :

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your device on same WiFi as your computer? Are you using a firewall that might block access?

Comment: Yes it's on the same Wifi as my computer. You mean a firewall on the router ? Because I don't have any on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of jevakallio, I figured out that the automatic DNS used by my iPhone blocked the request to my server.

Setting them to manual mode and putting the Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) made my app works on my iPhone.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem, added dns settings but luck, been stuck for days on this, simulator works fine, so annoying....